# Doctrine: multiple inversedBy relationship

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have following relationship table:

[image: Relationship diagram here]

My goal is to retrieve all the residents form table [Resident]. The following is my code:

```
public function getAllResidents(){
    $all_resident = $this->resident_repo->getAll(); //!!error thrown from here!!
}

public function getAll(){
    return $this->findAll();
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: 
 require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/models/Proxies/__CG__EntityDoctor.php):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory

 Filename: Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php

 Line Number: 209

 Backtrace:

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
 Line: 209 Function: _error_handler

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
 Line: 209 Function: require

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
 Line: 119 Function: getProxyDefinition

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
 Line: 2707 Function: getProxy

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php
 Line: 147 Function: createEntity

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php
 Line: 69 Function: hydrateRowData

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php
 Line: 150 Function: hydrateAllData

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php
 Line: 888 Function: hydrateAll

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php
 Line: 181 Function: loadAll

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php
 Line: 164 Function: findBy

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/models/Repository/ResidentRepository.php
 Line: 13 Function: findAll

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/controllers/ModelTest.php
 Line: 69 Function: getAllResident

 File:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/controllers/ModelTest.php
 Line: 21 Function: getAllResidents

 File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/index.php Line:
 315 Function: require_once


 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
 '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/models/Proxies/__CG__EntityDoctor.php'
 (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/lib/php') in
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
 on line 209 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Compile Error

 Message: require(): Failed opening required
 '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Final_Project/a18ux06/application/models/Proxies/__CG__EntityDoctor.php'
 (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/lib/php')

 Filename: Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php

 Line Number: 209

 Backtrace:
```

I am not sure what the problem is - I just started to learn doctrine. Is it because my [Resident] table has [2 many to one] relationship aka [2 inversedBy] for table [building and doctor]?

I have been stuck here for an entire day now! a quick help or a reference to what i could do would be very helpful. If extra stuffs are required let me know.

Comment: @user6910411 I made the edit. Hope that can help out a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Doctrin's default query functions are limited in what they can do.
So I had to write my own custom lower level SQL queries instead of trying to use `find`, `find_by`, etc... that are default from Doctrine.

Some places I used `QueryBuilder` and some places normal SQL queries.